# Добавление кнопки в UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

При создании кнопки кодом в ячейку с определенным индексом кнопка создается не активная...

```
    if ([cellIdentifier isEqual:@"second"]) {
    //Create the button and add it to the cell
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.tag = 555;
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 60.0f, 150.0f, 30.0f);
    [cell addSubview:button];
```

Пробывал доставать кнопку по тегу, так же не успешно...

- (void) customActionPressed: (UIButton *) button
  {

  if (button.tag == 555) {
      NSLog(@"Hello");

  }
  }

Comment: попробуйте добавить кнопку к `[cell.contentView addSubview:button];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такое решение.
Сперва создать `UIView` размером с ячейку, поместить в неё кнопку, затем эту view поместить в `contentView` область ячейки.

Для Вашего примера выглядит это так:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
button.tag = 555;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 130.0f, 30.0f);
[view addSubview:button];
[cell.contentView addSubview:view];
```

Ещё советую почитать теорию о tableview cell [вот здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).